# Ursina engine does not load texture from .mtl file

Tags: python-3.x

I make game and got error:
texture from .mtl file doesn't render.
I have a map folder and into it have folder with textures.
My code:

```
cube = Entity(model= 'sprites/map/cs_office.obj', scale=(.1,.1,.1), texture='sprites/map/cs_office.mtl')
```

I can use not only .mtl, how to solve it?
I use Ursina engine.

Answer (score 3):

For .obj and .mtl files, don't add an extension. For example, in your case:

```
cube = Entity(model="sprites/map/cs_office", scale=(.1, .1, .1), texture="sprites/map/cs_office")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I think it will be easier to transfer the game to panda3d

Comment: IM SORRY!!(I'm also new to ursina)! I saw a tutorial and in the tutorial there was a similar situation with .obj and .mtl files, and he imported the files without the ending...

Comment: The tutorial is nice tho, if you want to check it out, it's here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHSRaVeQxIk

Answer (score 1):

On my version of ursina engine (5.0.0) you can add the ".obj"/".mtl" extension.

But maybe the texture doesn't exist, or it doesn't fit right; for example, something is white in the texture and only this part of the texture lies on the 3D Model.